How does the behavior of this override of placement new change things?
I just came across a usage of placement new that I don't understand, which I suppose is not surprising since I've never used it at all.
// Copy event type and map data reference from  queue entry *pData to its
// local copy via placement new.
// Note: Can't use a setter nor assignment operator here because
// Event Data contains a reference member variable.
Data eventData;
new (&eventData) Io::Event::Data(*pData);

The Data class contains this:
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  METHOD NAME: Io::Event::Data::*operator new
//
/// Placement new operator
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void *operator new(size_t size UNUSED, void *pMem) { return pMem; };

What is the effect of the overridden placement new operator?  If it did not exist, then the class's copy constructor would be invoked.  But what does this do?  I did find an example of an override looking exactly like this elsewhere on SO, but it didn't explain it.  Does the use of this override merely copy the bytes from the source location into the target location?

Code looks like UB to me, because eventData is constructed twice. Once in the declaration and once in the placement new.

My first question is: why would the use of a reference variable in a data structure make assignment or copy construction a problem? A reference variable in a class automatically deletes the special members.

In this particular case, it makes no sense -- it provides memory for the object, and constructs it. Even on top of the existing one, which means they have to careful what the class can or cannot contain. Myself, I'm currently getting the memory for an object that was allocated by C code, and I use placement-new to construct a C++ object into it (and later call the destructor myself to clean it up, before calling the C-code to free the memory).

Having a reference member variable is a weak reason for this use of placement new. Just store a pointer or reference_wrapper instead.

Regular new both allocates storage and constructs an object. Placement new is generally used when you only want to construct, where the storage has come from somewhere else. Usually that storage is uninitialised memory (for example a char array) but here it's an already constructed object, that's the suspicious part.

Expanding on Doug's comment above: Since you can only set what a reference refers to at initialization, an assignment operator cannot change what the reference refers to. This forces you to write a custom assignment operator and may make assigning impossible because it can't make the two objects equal.

Before calling placement new on top of a living object, destruct that object first, and the do the placement new on top of the carcass of the former object.  Not recommended, though.  Lots of sharp edges to hurt yourself.

The placement new is usually used when you want to place a variable in a specific location or address.  This could be special memory or in a specific memory pool.  If you don't need the extra effort of concern of specialized memory areas, refrain from placement new.

@user4581301 an assignment operator cannot change what the reference refers to This was true prior to c++20. You can now overwrite references to refer to other, same type, objects. You need to do placement new of the entire object and so replace all object values even if they are unchanged. The reference itself can't be accessed directly as it doesn't have a named identity.
